# Factoring a derivative in Calculus.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Please see below. I'm not sure where the $\frac32$ and $\frac12$ are coming from when it appears some of the values should cancel out. Please help or correct me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/161UD.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the coefficients in the last line? The previous line is
$$=\frac{1}{2}(\theta^{1/2}+\theta^{-3/2}-\theta^{-1/2}-\theta^{-5/2}) +(\theta^{1/2}+\theta^{-1/2}-\theta^{-3/2}-\theta^{-5/2}).$$
There is a $\frac{1}{2} \theta^{1/2}$ in the first summand and $1*\theta^{1/2}$ in the second summand, so $\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\theta}$, and similarly a $-\frac{1}{2} \theta^{-5/2}$ in the first summand and a $-1*\theta^{-5/2}$ in the second summand, so in total there  is $-\frac{3}{2} \theta^{-5/2} = -\frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\theta^5}}$, and combining these we get the left summand in the bottom line. Similarly for $\theta^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\theta}}$ and $\theta^{-3/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\theta^3}}$ (notice the first summand has $-\frac{1}{2} \theta^{-1/2}$ and the second summand has $+\theta^{-1/2}$, hence the $+\frac{1}{2} \theta^{-1/2}$).